# Access array from java controller

Tags: java, jquery, model-view-controller, multipartform-data

How can I send an array with form data and access it from java controller?

I tried the code for passing array as

```
ajaxData.append('Array', myarray)
```

Also tried to access from java controller as

```
@RequestParam("Array") List<Integer> newArray
```

It is not working.

Comment: Why dont you pass the complete array as part of json. Like {"ArrayData":[{"data1":"value1"},{"data2":"value2"}]}

Comment: It is a dynamic array and I stored the array into session storage. While passing the ajax form data to the form data I appended the array. Instead of array if it was a string I was able to access the string value as String a=request.getParameter("StringAppend"); from java controller. The string was appended to form data like ajaxData.append('StringAppend', 'new');

Answer (score 0):

You should use Model Object to get all the formdata values. You can use @ModelAttribute at controller's method level.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/yourmapping")
public String formProcessing(@ModelAttribute FormModel formData){

}

class FormModel{
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private MultipartFile file;
   ...
}
```

http://www.startwithjava.com/spring-boot-multiple-files-upload-with-other-input-fields/